# The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "XYZ" was unable to begin a distributed transaction

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, linked-server

Estou tentando realizar um *update* em uma base de dados em outro servidor através de um LINKED SERVER configurado no meu servidor local. Já testei e está funcionando perfeitamente quando utilizo *queries* no SGBD.

Em minha aplicação web, utilizo hibernate 3.5 e, quando tento realizar a mesma query, recebo esse erro:

"The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "XYZ" was unable to begin a distributed transaction"

Porém, se tento realizar a mesma operação via JDBC puro, funciona perfeitamente.

Qual o problema do *hibernate* com os acessos a servidores externos?